# How can I possibly know if SQLcommand is properly disposed?

Tags: c#, dispose, sqlcommand

How can I possibly know if SQLcommand is properly disposed?

My problem is that my code always returns false because my sqlcommand is not equivalent to null

How can I possibly fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
private SqlCommand Command()
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, Connection);
        cmd.StatementCompleted += new StatementCompletedEventHandler(cmd_StatementCompleted);
        return cmd;
    }

    private void cmd_StatementCompleted(object sender, StatementCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((SqlCommand)sender).Dispose();
    }

    public object GetScalarResult()
    {
        Command();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType;

        con.Open();

        return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    public bool IsDisposedChecker()
    {
        if (cmd == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My IsDisposedChecker function always returns false so that means sqlcommand is not properly disposed?

Comment: `Dispose()` does **not** reset the pointer to null. So the disposedChecker function does not work this way.. See below..

Comment: so instead of null what should i use @JeroenvanLangen ?

Comment: Also, Disposing on StatementComplete looks a bit silly. After the command is complete, don't you want to handle the results of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dispose()` does **not** reset the pointer to null. So the ISDisposedChecker function does not work this way..

Dispose isn't a destructor..

---

I wouldn't implement a dispose-checker, I would put the Dispose responsibility to the caller method if you want to return the SqlCommand as result.

```
private SqlCommand Command()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, Connection);
    return cmd;
}

private void Test()
{
    // a using block is very safe, it will dispose the command 
    // even when exceptions are thrown.
    using(SqlCommand command = Command())
    {
        // do your thing....
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in your code, StatementCompleted is not required.. as user is only disposing object here